# XSLT how to remove the value of nodes not matched

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract the aisStatic bloc (in XML format) in the following document :

```
<Document>
    <numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults>
    <timeCreated>2020-07-17T09:25:12Z</timeCreated>
    <returnCode>200</returnCode>
    <message>OK</message>
    <numVessels>1</numVessels>
    <vessels>
        <aisStatic>
            <name>My beautiful vessel</name>
            <mmsi>0000000000</mmsi>
            <imo>0000000</imo>
            <callsign>XXXX</callsign>
            <flag>Russia</flag>
            <length>140</length>
            <width>17</width>
            <typeOfShipAndCargo>80</typeOfShipAndCargo>
            <aisShiptype>tankships</aisShiptype>
            <updateTime>2018-03-10T14:46:24Z</updateTime>
            <aisClass>A</aisClass>
        </aisStatic>
        <aisVoyage>
            <updateTime>2020-07-17T09:20:34Z</updateTime>
            <eta>2020-07-18T12:00:00Z</eta>
            ...
```

XSLT tranformation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/Document/vessels">
    <xsl:copy-of select="aisStatic"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I retrieve also the value of the nodes before aisStatic like that :

```
    1
    2020-07-17T09:25:12Z
    200
    OK
    1
        <aisStatic>
            <name>My beautiful vessel</name>
            <mmsi>0000000000</mmsi>
            <imo>0000000</imo>
            <callsign>XXXX</callsign>
```

What is the way to get only the expected bloc ?

Answer (score 0):

Match on `/` and for the copy-of use `select="Document/vessels/aisStatic"`

Answer (score 0):

**In a fully "push style"**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(ancestor-or-self::aisStatic)]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(ancestor-or-self::aisStatic)]/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (added closing tags to make it well-formed) document:

```
<Document>
    <numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults>
    <timeCreated>2020-07-17T09:25:12Z</timeCreated>
    <returnCode>200</returnCode>
    <message>OK</message>
    <numVessels>1</numVessels>
    <vessels>
        <aisStatic>
            <name>My beautiful vessel</name>
            <mmsi>0000000000</mmsi>
            <imo>0000000</imo>
            <callsign>XXXX</callsign>
            <flag>Russia</flag>
            <length>140</length>
            <width>17</width>
            <typeOfShipAndCargo>80</typeOfShipAndCargo>
            <aisShiptype>tankships</aisShiptype>
            <updateTime>2018-03-10T14:46:24Z</updateTime>
            <aisClass>A</aisClass>
        </aisStatic>
        <aisVoyage>
            <updateTime>2020-07-17T09:20:34Z</updateTime>
            <eta>2020-07-18T12:00:00Z</eta>
        </aisVoyage>
   </vessels>
</Document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<aisStatic>
    <name>My beautiful vessel</name>
    <mmsi>0000000000</mmsi>
    <imo>0000000</imo>
    <callsign>XXXX</callsign>
    <flag>Russia</flag>
    <length>140</length>
    <width>17</width>
    <typeOfShipAndCargo>80</typeOfShipAndCargo>
    <aisShiptype>tankships</aisShiptype>
    <updateTime>2018-03-10T14:46:24Z</updateTime>
    <aisClass>A</aisClass>
</aisStatic>
```